# How do you move field content into another twig template?

Tags: theming, 8

This is specifically for Drupal 8. I know how to do this in D7.

I'm developing a custom theme. I know how to create and change individual Twig field templates, but I'm not able to find much info on consolidating field data from individual twig templates into one template.

Specifically, I'm trying to move the field_tag data from field--node--field-tags.html.twig into the same area as he breadcrumbs.

I have two Twig templates; one for tags and one for breadcrumbs. The tags need to appear on the same line and in the same block area as the breadcrumbs.

Any ideas on how to do this? I can't get the Tags data to render. I thought it would be as easy as using {{ content.field_tags }} to make it render, but that doesn't do anything.

Comment: One way to do this is to make a View Mode that just shows the term field and use Views to create a new Block. Set a contextual argument for content ID from URL, and place your block. Then you can theme that view mode with normal twig templates. Basically, if you are outside the scope of rendering a node, `{{ content.field_name }}` isn't going to do anything, but you can use Views to do this without needing any additional modules.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Kevin. Since Drupal 8 uses configurations, is all of that exportable as a configuration? It also has to work after being installed with a profile. I've tried to not use views at all because the client this is being passed to will not have permission to edit views at all.

Comment: Yes, Views and view modes are exportable.

Comment: Excellent. I wasn't sure about the Views modes. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: View modes are under Admin > Structure > Display modes > View modes. Then you need to enable that on the content type under Manage Display > Custom Display Settings, then click into that View Mode tab, and set the one taxonomy field to display.